# Error 500 in Symfony when trying to use Auth0

Tags: php, symfony, auth0

I did download the example that appears in the auth0 (https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/backend/php-symfony) , enter the customer id and the secret id gives api that i use as it appears in the tutorial , when I try to access the **http://localhost:8000/api/ping** that is protected by the Auth0 is giving me this error **Signature verification failed**, already did this to someone ? What am I doing wrong?

Error Image

[image]

Log Image

[image]

Comment: Have you tried cache clear? Might be something wrong with route or couldn't get token. Also it was happened due to you have use linux and have trouble with owner of folder.

Comment: Yes I've cleared the cache and remains the same

Answer (score 0):

Your API is likely using a different client_secret than the one used to issue the token. Make sure it is properly configured her: https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/backend/php-symfony#3-configure-your-auth0-app-data

The secret in the API must be the same configured in the API dashboard on Auth0 (**Dashboard > APIs > {your API} > Settings**). Look for "signing secret".

Then click on the **"Test"** tab on our API definition. You'll see a test token available there. Make the same Postman call with that token and it should work.

> PS: looking at the tutorial, I think it needs to be updated (not architecturally, but rather in the configuration. I the SDK & docs team aware.

Comment: I was careful to insert the client_secret and right client_id and continues to this error, I do not know what might be causing this

Comment: Can you copy the token into the clipboard, and paste it to jwt.io ? Then use the client_secret to validate it again.

Comment: I did what you said and gives Invalid Signature ([Image](https://s22.postimg.org/u82nfbmu9/Captura_de_ecra_2016_11_04_a_s_14_44_28.png)  , [Image2](https://s15.postimg.org/folejo9aj/Captura_de_ecra_2016_11_04_a_s_14_51_36.png) ) but if I change the Signing Secret gives Signature Verified ([Image](https://s22.postimg.org/65ltkg675/Captura_de_ecra_2016_11_04_a_s_14_44_53.png))

Comment: Also I tried with global client secret and did not work

Comment: You are using the `client_secret` of the client in the server. You should configure the server with the "signing secret" (under "Settings" in the API).

Comment: Where and insert the "signing secret" in symfony ?